# How to make an element have a position of both relative and absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have a parent element with a child element and the child element is the parent element of a child element like this:

```
<div class="father">

    <div class="child">
        
        <div class="child-of-child"></div>


    </div>
    
</div>
```

And CSS like this:

```
.father{
    position: relative;
}

.child{
    position: absolute;
}

.child-of-child{
    position: absolute;
}
```

But I want the div named child to be `position: absolute;` to the father like it is now, and I also want it to be `position: relative;` to the div named `child-of-child` so that I can move the `child-of-child` inside `child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that the `.child` is **absolutely** positioned, any `.child-of-child` can be **absolutely** positioned in relation to the `.child`. This means that the `.child` does not need to be given **position: relative** for the `.child-of-child` to be absolutely positioned with respect to it.

You can confidently use your CSS.